# If I have the .yml file (containing workflows/jobs/actions) in multiple branches, which one is the active?

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, github-actions, continuous-deployment, building-github-actions

Let's say I have two branches, 'main' and 'work' - they both are the exact same project, however there's one difference - the 'work' branch contains a slightly different workflow (for example, one contains a conditional statement `if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' }}`)

So which file will be the one that's the one from which the actions are derived?

From what file (or which branch) do the actions under 'actions' tab come from?

One more question:

Let's say I have a .yml file containing a workflow (that triggers on push). Now, I will push a new .yml file with some changes - which .yml file will be the one that runs? The one thats already active on the repo or the one that's getting pushed?

Comment: When you just inform the `push` trigger, it should trigger for each branch you perform a `push`, using the branch workflow. If you want to run a workflow with a `push` trigger only for a specific branch, you could use a conditional such as `if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'` in the workflow.

Comment: You might also be interested by this part of the [Github documentation about workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#about-workflow-events), used in this [answer](https://github.community/t/workflow-files-only-picked-up-from-master/16129/16). Where you'll see that _For example, if the event occurred on a particular repository branch, then the workflow files must be present in the repository on that branch._

Comment: @GuiFalourd what if the .yml file is different in each branch? Which will then take precedence?

Comment: It will run the workflow from the branch you push the code. [I tested it here if you want to check](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/workflows/workflow-tester4.yml) with 2 different branches (main and dev)

Comment: @GuiFalourd I posted a comment as an answer to this question, the character limit + formatting didn't let me answer here

Answer (score 2):

@GuiFalourd I did some tests myself, and here's what I've found out myself:

(in this situation we have two branches, 'main' and 'work', both have their respective .yml files)

- The workflow that runs is the one that was pushed, i.e. workflows run on push
- On push to 'work', the workflow in 'work' runs
- On push to 'main', the workflow in 'main' runs
- On push to 'main' only Main-YML runs even though in Work-YML push to main is configured as event
- 'Work-YML' doesn't run on push to 'work' if trigger isn't configured
- .yml in 'work' doesn't run on push to main even if it has configured push to main as trigger

Agree/Disagree?

This thread I've found mirrors the outcome of my test:

https://github.community/t/workflow-files-only-picked-up-from-master/16129/7

That's mad, I cannot get the 'work.yml' file to run unless I push directly to 'work' branch...

Comment: It's exactly as you said 

Comment: And if you want to run an operation for a specific condition (the one from the work branch for example) you can use a `if conditio ` in your main workflow to perform the same operation according to the expression you inform.